# Android, Firebase: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16

Tags: android, firebase

My **app/build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when I try to build my Android project I get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0]
```

I can't change **minSdkVersion**  because this is the client's requirement - run Android application on min. ver = 15

Comment: You can't do it. The firebase ui has a minSDK = 16. In any case with api=16 you will cover over the 99% of the devices. What is your problem?? Check https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: The problem is... that this is the client's requirement, minSdkVersion = 15

Comment: **It doesn't change the answer, you can't also if they want !** Check the dashboard. No one has a device with api15. In any case you can do 2 versions. One with minSdk=15 and maxSdk=15, another one with minSdk=16. Check https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't change minSdkVersion because this is the client's requirement - run Adnroid application on min. ver = 15

You **can't do** it since you are using some dependencies with `minSdk = 16` (in your case the [firebase-ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/library/build.gradle#L9) has a **minSdk=16**).

You can choose an older version of the dependencies but you will have always problems in the future since you will not able to update them.

As you can check in the [official dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), today with **minSdk=16 you will cover over the 99% of the devices**.

In any case, if it is a strong requirement of the customer **you can [create multiple APKs for Different API Levels](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html)**.

It means that you can create different flavors in your build.gradle with a different level of api and different dependencies. In this way you will be able to support device with api 15 and also the new versions of the libraries used.

```
productFlavors {

    // priority than the second, and so on.
    minApi15 {
      minSdkVersion '15'
      ...
    }

    minApi16 {
      minSdkVersion '16'
   }
}

dependencies {
  minApi15Compile xxxxx
  minApi16Compile xxxxx
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you need to downgrade the version of your `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0`.

`2.3.0` is the latest version. According to [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) you need to use an earlier version which allow you to use `minSdkVersion 15`.

Hope it helps.